# AWS Codebuild error while installing SASSC gem wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I'm running a Codestar project. Sample app installs fine. When I add my application in with SASSC get failure, because of Ruby version. Is there away to notify CodeBuild to upgrade Ruby version? tried looking through buildspec.yml am I anywhere close? trying to google.

In middle of build logs

```
Installing sassc 2.0.0 with native extensions
 Gem::InstallError: sassc requires Ruby version >= 2.3.3.
```

At end of build logs

```
An error occurred while installing sassc (2.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 [Container] 2018/12/31 04:17:42 Command did not exit successfully bundle install exit status 5
[Container] 2018/12/31 04:17:42 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: false
[Container] 2018/12/31 04:17:42 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: bundle install. Reason: exit status 5
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Codebuild environment from AWS Linux distro to Ubuntu with Ruby 2.5.3 which fixed my problem. Unless someone has a better answer.